# Description is not outputting the expected files correctly, coming in as blank files

Tags: excel, vba

So as stated in the title, I am running this VBA script and it seems that the specification and summ are outputing as expected but for some reason the Des (description) is not outputting anything at all although I have data that should be outputted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub productInfo()
    
    Dim OutputPath As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Header As String
    Dim File As String
    Dim Product As String

    Dim Productnum As Integer
    
    Dim fn As Integer
    Dim Spec As Integer
    Dim Des As Integer
    Dim Summ As Integer
    Dim Subtitle As Integer
    
    'k & r are iterating rows
    'i & c are iterating columns
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim LC As Long
    
    'define column number for file name
    fn = Sheets("arguments").Cells(2, 2)
    'define spec/datasheet column'
    Spec = Sheets("arguments").Cells(3, 2)
    'define description column
    Des = Sheets("arguments").Cells(4, 2)
    'define summary column
    Summ = Sheets("arguments").Cells(5, 2)
    'define subtitle column
    Subtitle = Sheets("arguments").Cells(6, 2)
    
    Productnum = FreeFile
    LR = Sheets("products").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = Sheets("products").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    OutputPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + Sheets("arguments").Cells(1, 2)
    If Len(Dir(OutputPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir OutputPath
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To LC
        If i = 1 Or i = 7 Or i = 8 Then
            Header = Sheets("products").Cells(1, i)
            Path = OutputPath + "\" + Header
            If Len(Dir(Path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir Path
            End If
        End If
        
        For k = 2 To LR
            Product = Sheets("products").Cells(k, fn)
            If InStr(Path, "description") Then
                File = Path + "\" + Product + "_DESCRIPTION.html"
            ElseIf InStr(Path, "summary") Then
                File = Path + "\" + Product + "_SUMMARY.html"
            Else
                File = Path + "\" + Product + ".html"
            End If
            Open File For Output As Productnum

                Select Case i
                    Case Spec
                        If Sheets("products").Cells(k, i).Value = "" Then
                            Print #Productnum, "<a href=../" + Product + ".html> See DataSheet </a>"
                        End If
                    Case Des, Summ
                        If Sheets("products").Cells(k, i).Value = "" Then
                            Print #Productnum, ArraySubstitute(Sheets("products").Cells(k, Subtitle), Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)
                        Else
                            Print #Productnum, ArraySubstitute(Sheets("products").Cells(k, i), Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)
                            End If
                    Case Else
                        Print #Productnum, ArraySubstitute(Sheets("products").Cells(k, i), Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)
                    End Select
                    
'                Select Case True
'                    Case Spec = i and Des = i and Summ = i and vbNullString
'                        Sheets("products").Cells(k, i).Value = Print #Productnum, "<a href=../" + Product + "_datasheet.pdf> See DataSheet </a>"
'                    Case Not Spec = i And Des = i And Summ = i And vbNullString
'                        Print #Productnum, ArraySubstitute(Sheets("products").Cells(k, Subtitle), Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)
'                    Case Else
'                        Print #Productnum, ArraySubstitute(Sheets("products").Cells(k, i), Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)
'                End Select
                    
            Close Productnum
            
        Next k
    Next i

    
End Sub
```

Here is my table that I am using

| description | main_image | product_link | product_sku | product_sub_title | products_zoom_image | specification | summary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 |  |  | LMX-0602-S3-V2 | Subtitle1 |  |  | Summ1 |
|  |  |  | LMX-1202M-SFP-T | Subtitle2 |  |  | Summ2 |
| Product2 |  |  | LMX-1202M-SFP | Subtitle3 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | LMX-0602-M-T-V2 | Subtitle4 |  |  | Summ4 |
| Product3 |  |  | LMX-0602-M-V2 | Subtitle5 |  |  |  |

Here is my arguments table

| output path | Output |
| --- | --- |
| sku | 4 |
| datasheet | 7 |
| description | 1 |
| summary | 8 |
| sub | 5 |

Comment: You're using `select` to print... if you meet the other criteria, before the case for `des` then it exits the `select`.  You will need to modify your criteria for `select` or find another approach.

Comment: @Cyril I have just updated the code again, and I made some more changes, the code is now outputting into the description file, but it is pulling from the wrong column, any ideas?

Comment: Look at the column references in your `arraySubstitute()`, including the `listColumns()` references.  Only the positive case for `des, summ` uses column = `subtitle`.

Comment: @Cyril That's what is suppose to come out, but for some reason it's pulling the column that is one less than the expected column for that. Not to mention that when I ran my program, the description should be returning as false and be running the else statement that prints the regular cell information after cleaning it. 
EDIT - It looks like that when I debugged it, it runs once through correctly, but then it runs it again and set it up with the wrong column.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `Select` could be reworked.  Here's a quick mock-up:

```
Select Case True
    Case Spec = i and Des = i and Summ = i and vbNullString Sheets("products").Cells(k, i).Value = 
        Print #Productnum, "<a href=../" + Product + "_datasheet.pdf> See DataSheet </a>"
    Case Not Spec = i and Des = i and Summ = i and vbNullString 
        Print #Productnum, ArraySubstitute(Sheets("products").Cells(k, Subtitle), Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)
    Case Else 
        Print #Productnum, ArraySubstitute(Sheets("products").Cells(k, i), Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, Sheets("cleaner").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)
End Select
```

Need to check out the second `case` above, as it doesn't feel right, but where you had the same "else" scenario, you shouldn't need to keep repeating the same line.

Note that this printing to a single cell doesn't really tell us why a description (`des`) field isn't being filled in... you simply `Print` to each cell in the looped array, which may indicate a criteria is not being met.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Th reason why I have the else scenario being repeated is because the renaming of the file name with the sub-title is only for Des and Summ.
So for the 2nd part - would it be possible to explain to me why my initial program when ran it returns the correct statements for Summ but not for Des, I understand that you stated that there is a criteria most likely not being met, but I'm uncertain on how to troubleshoot that. Sorry i'm fairly new to vba

Comment: @Shadobladez my quick guess would be that `Des = Sheets("arguments").Cells(4, 2)` does not equal `i`, so your `Select` is ending without a print.

Comment: here is the "arguments" table -

 output path | Output  |   |   |   |   |   |   
-------------|---------|---|---|---|---|---|---
 sku         | 4       |   |   |   |   |   |   
 datasheet   | 7       |   |   |   |   |   |   
 description | 1       |   |   |   |   |   |   
 summary     | 8       |   |   |   |   |   |   
 sub         | 5       |   |   |   |   |   |